# How to access main .bash_profile from within an anaconda virtual environment?

Tags: python, bash, shell, anaconda

I have a .bash_profile file ready to go. When I activate my virtual environment I can't access it. The environment bash_profile is blank. Is there a way to 'import' my normal bash_profile into all/select virtual environments

I'm creating the virtual environments through the anaconda distribution, which messes with the path for the .bash_profile a bit, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I just had to source the 'home' bash_profile with `source ~/.bash_profile` from within the environment.

Comment: Though, I think this has to be done for every start of the environment. Might put that command in 'its own' profile.